# Jenkinsfile: Check that a given param wildcard contains specific folder

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job that runs tests. I need to do some specific preparation step only if the given tests wildcard param (`SPEC_LOCATION=tests/**/*.ts`) contains a specific sub-folder, i.e. `service-one`.

So the question is: How to do an expression that would return `True` if `SPEC_LOCATION` wildcard matches `tests/service-one`, and `False` if it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

grep the pattern in the variable list:

```
if echo $SPEC_LOCATION | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -wq '^tests/service-one'; then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I use this to conditionally execute a step inside Jenkinsfile?